# shorten excel formula to count over multiple tables on multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I'm trying to create a data table that breaks down information from a series of activities with young people over a number of sessions. my main sheets have 3 tables for attendance, waiting list and cancellations and there are 16 sheets for the different activities. I also have a separate 'Codes' sheet with information like age ranges, gender, job role of referrer etc.
currently I have very long formula to count my totals across the sheets and want to try and shorten it;
for example: to count how many 8 year olds were referred onto the activities i have the current formula to count just 1 day =COUNTIF(MainDay1[Age],Codes!B13)+COUNTIF(WaitingDay1[Age],Codes!B13)+COUNTIF(CancelDay1[Age],Codes!B13)
and this is then repeated again and again to take in all 16 days creating a very long formuula.

is there a way i can condense and shorten this down?

thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your tables are consistently named, i.e.:

*MainDay1, MainDay2, ..., MainDay16*

*WaitingDay1, WaitingDay2, ..., WaitingDay16*

*CancelDay1, CancelDay2, ..., CancelDay16*

`=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"MainDay";"WaitingDay";"CancelDay"}&SEQUENCE(,16)&"[Age]"),Codes!B13))`

where the 16 in the part

`SEQUENCE(,16)`

represents the number of sheets being queried (and can be replaced with a static equivalent if you don't have access to the `SEQUENCE` function).

Note that it is important that the two constructions:

`{"MainDay";"WaitingDay";"CancelDay"}`

and

`SEQUENCE(,16)`

result in *orthogonal* arrays, i.e. one a vertical array, the other horizontal. For English-language versions of Excel, the semicolon represents the separator in vertical arrays.

Comment: cheers. i think i understand so giving it a try.

Comment: brilliant, all works as it should. thank you for this.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!